# Is it really possible to completely deactivate the desktop via the registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-registry

I've heard that there is the possibility to remove the taskbar and desktop (making both invisible) via a registry entry.

As I didn't find anything there I'm wondering if this is true and if so which entries that would be?

Comment: are you interested in Windows xp or 7?

Comment: If it is the same for both then both else windows xp I think primarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's called active shell executable.

```
Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Name: Shell

Type: REG_SZ

Value: Explorer.exe
```

Change it to, say, `firefox.exe` and you have yourself a kiosk-mode workstation. (Remember, Ctrl+Alt+Delete is still accessible in that case)